# How do I get my discord bot react to it being mentioned?

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I'm trying to get my JavaScript Discord bot to react to being mentioned in discord. However, it doesn't do anything when someone mentions it.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const keepAlive = require('./server');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.toString().toLowerCase().includes('@class of 2020 assistant')) {
    message.author.send('Your assistance ticket haassistancese wait for a DM from ageekdude.');
    const ageekdude = client.users.cache.get('571713056673890324');
    if (ageekdude) ageekdude.send(`${message.author} has requested an assistance ticket.`)
}
});

keepAlive();
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Could someone please give me a suggestion on how I get the bot to react to it being mentioned?

Comment: What type of mention are you trying to detect ? A user mention, role mention ..?

Comment: I'm trying to get it to detect a user being mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your bot react to it being mentionned, this if statement should be enough :

```js
if (/<@!YourBotID>|<@YourBotID>/.test(message.content)) {
    return message.reply('hey, you mentioned me !');
}
```

You'll need to use the `!` as well because user mentions are not the same on PC and mobile.
Happy coding ;)